# Can a 10th Level Bard use Magical secrets to gain 5th level Paladin spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, bard

Basically I am looking at having my bard take Banishing Smite and Destructive wave as his spells for magical secrets.  This would be to increase his damage output as a Valour Bard.  The description of Magical secrets suggests I can, but Paladins can't usually take these spells until they are around 17th Level.  Has anyone seen anything that would suggest that Bards cannot take Paladin or Ranger spells?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Magical Secrets lets you choose spells of a level you can cast.

By 10th level a bard can cast 5th level spells. Banishing Smite and Destructive Wave are both 5th level spells... There's nothing stopping you from choosing these spells.